# BCrypt::Password Ruby

Tags: ruby, bcrypt

I'm currently working on Ruby and I can't get, what is the difference between

```
def create_hash_digest(password)
  BCrypt::Password.create(password)
end

def verify_hash_digest(password)
  BCrypt::Password.new(password)
end
```

This sample is taken from Udemy course on complete Ruby on Rails

Comment: Did you read the docs for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#create` is used to Hash a secret, returning a `BCrypt::Password` instance i.e encryption

`#new` is used to decrypt `BCrypt::Password` instance with the data from a stored hash.

```
include BCrypt
# hash a user's password
@password = Password.create("my grand secret")
@password #=> "$2a$12$C5.FIvVDS9W4AYZ/Ib37YuWd/7ozp1UaMhU28UKrfSxp2oDchbi3K"

# store it safely @user.update_attribute(:password, @password)

# read it back
@user.reload!
@db_password = Password.new(@user.password)

# compare it after retrieval
@db_password == "my grand secret" #=> true
@db_password == "a paltry guess" #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

`#create` converts your password into a hash:

```
'my_password' ~> '$2a$12$C5.FIvVDS9W4AYZ/Ib37...'
```

while `#new` converts it back.

Comment: tnx @Viktor for updating!